# Should I use custom headers or useragent header to send device informations to the server

Tags: http, http-headers, user-agent

Every time I send a API request to my server I want send information like device type and OS version (from my mobile app). My first thought is to use User Agent but I wonder if there's any benefits to use custom http header like "X-deviceType" or/and "X-osVersion" instead.

Comment: I am surprised this question hasn't got any answers. I am also wondering the same, seems like there should be a standard already to send these kind of stuff since mobile use has grown so much

Comment: What is the problem you're trying to solve by sending this data?

Answer (score 1):

I am using the X-Device HTTP Header.

Works well for the most part, however I have noticed that some requests from behind a proxy seem to be stripping the data from that header.

Answer (score 1):

Remember that the client can change the User-agent by using a tweaked mobile browser or a proxy.

But by setting custom headers, you show that you are seeking to collect this kind of data. We suppose that the law allows you to collect it. It could make a malicious actor to change/erase them or also make a bot to do so. Note also that the client could change the headers and their content with a proxy.

It is interesting to note that [RFC6648](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6648#appendix-B) stipulates "Some parameters will [n]ever be standardized. In this case, implementation-specific and private-use parameters could at least incorporate the organization's name (e.g., "ExampleInc-foo" or, consistent with [RFC4288], "VND.ExampleInc.foo") or primary domain name (e.g., "com.example.foo" or a Uniform Resource Identifier [RFC3986] such as "http://example.com/foo")."

A legit use case would be to delegate the User-Agent parsing client side. A benefit would be to save computational resources on the server, at the cost of modified network bandswitch. This could or could not balance well with the above.